# Outlook just hangs while debugging VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am using `Visual Studio 2013` and trying to develop a `C#` `Outlook Add-In` project for `Outlook 2013` client installations at my enterprise employer.

What could cause `Outlook` to not load completely, i.e. upon pressing **F5** to **Start Debugging** my application via the `VS IDE`, the `Outlook` **Splash Screen** loads for a second, but `Outlook` never actually loads. Via the **Task Manager**, I am able to see a process for `Outlook` running in the background, but it never materializes into an **App** process.

I have done the following: in the project's **Properties** page, I have set `Outlook.EXE` local path as the Start an external program and also set the working directory.

When I run my code "Start Without Debugging", `Outlook` indeed does load and I can run my `Outlook Add-In`, but I am not able to step through my code which, of course, is invaluable.

Any ideas on what I should maybe look for?

**UPDATE:**

As per @Sarvesh's answer, I created a new **Outlook Add-In** project without setting any **Properties** and just one line of code as shown and still the same behavior:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Writeline("ThisAddIn_Startup was called...");
}
```

Comment: Can you try this new addin code after disabling older addin?

Comment: Yes, I actually disabled the previous COM Add-In within Outlook. I even loaded Visual Studio as Administrator to see if maybe it was a permissions issue but still no luck. I'm stumped since I don't know where to look, especially since the entry point of my code does not even get hit. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> In the project's Properties page, I have set Outlook's local path as
>   the Start an external program and also set the working directory.

Why you have set these?

If you are developing VSTO addin using templates provided by VS, you don't need to set these properties manually.

Set it back to default and then Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, only one instance of Outlook can be run at the same time. So, first of all check out the list of running processes for Outlook.exe before starting your project. Only then you can start your add-in under the debugger.

Also I'd suggest disabling all other add-ins in Outlook. Outlook may disable add-ins that take a lot of time for loading. Try to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in project. Set a breakppoint to the Startup event handler and run it under the debugger. Does it work?

Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.

For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold.

Make sure that the add-in is always enabled.

See [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679(v=office.15).aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue just recently - I resolved it by building and installing the addin in Outlook, which when launched threw an error and popped up with the exception.

In the end, the solution to my issue was to create a registry key in the 64-bit hive named `EnableVSTOLocalUNC` set to value `00000001` (as a dword) in the key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Vsto
Runtime Setup\v4]`.

[Here are some other potential issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/10/08/troubleshooting-common-vsto-issues-part-2.aspx) you may come across once you've installed the addin.